# Trying to wire up my new cooktop to my junction box

Tags: electrical

My cooktop has yellow and green wire, black wire, brown wire - I think it’s sort of a brownish-red, and then I have a blue wire and a grey wire which are wired together.

My junction box has three wires: yellow and green wire, red wire, and the black wire.

Can you tell me the best way to wire it up? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you on this planet and what make/model is the cooktop?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What do the installation instructions say?

Comment: Can you snap a picture of the circuit breaker or fuse?

Comment: The green is ground  (Green& yellow) do you have 3 phase power or is the cook top rated for multiple voltages?

Comment: What size are the wires at that junction?